# I want to hide all other div's when i click on one div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a software were i need to hide all other div's when i click on another div. what happens now is that the div's just stack on top of each other. and the div only dissapears when i click the same div again.

i already tried some of the JavaScript and jQuery code on this platform but can't quite figure it out myself.

--- THIS IS THE SCRIPT IM USING TO SHOW AND HIDE THE DIV'S ---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if(e.style.display == 'block')
                e.style.display = 'none';
            else
                e.style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
```

--- THESE ARE MY CLICKABLE AREA'S WHERE THE USER CAN CLICK ON TO SHOW AND HIDE A DIV ---

```
 <div class="div-voog" id=""> <img class="map" src="images/tekening-oog-vrouw-550px.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
        <map name="Map" id="Map">




     <area onclick="toggle_visibility('vooglid');" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords=170,251,159,253,140,251,134,249,126,244,121,241,118,237,114,226,113,221,118,214,128,204,141,195,160,187,176,178,194,171,208,165,230,157,249,155,268,153,284,151,300,151,326,154,341,158,358,168,371,178,380,190,394,209,402,221,408,235,412,244,403,247,392,242,378,231,366,219,347,207,334,203,316,199,286,199,263,203,246,208,221,218" />
        <area onclick="toggle_visibility('vwimpers');" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="170,251,159,253,140,251,134,249,126,244,121,241,118,237,114,226,113,221,118,214,128,204,141,195,160,187,176,178,194,171,208,165,230,157,249,155,268,153,284,151,300,151,326,154,341,158,358,168,371,178,380,190,394,209,402,221,408,235,412,244,403,247,392,242,378,231,366,219,347,207,334,203,316,199,286,199,263,203,246,208,221,218" />
        <area onclick="toggle_visibility('vwenkbrauw');" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="43,157,62,120,84,103,114,85,132,75,151,65,191,47,204,38,232,31,268,31,298,31,317,31,339,33,365,42,390,47,408,51,429,59,445,61,467,69,484,74,501,85,504,127,498,141,494,146,471,136,446,123,432,119,412,113,396,108,376,100,362,96,354,93,334,90,321,90,308,89,295,87,271,83,260,81,232,75,218,74,207,73,192,73,181,76,150,95,122,109,102,118,78,138,62,149,54,158,49,163,47,167" />
        <area onclick="toggle_visibility('vooghoek');" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="388,275,396,270,401,270,407,266,408,263,411,258,420,263,425,269,428,273,432,278,435,280,434,282,434,285,422,284,414,279" />

    </map>
</div>
```

--- AND THESE ARE MY DIV'S CONTAINING THE INFORMATION IT HAS TO SHOW AND HIDE ---

```
<div class="test" id="vooglid"> Symptoom ooglid</div>
<div class="test22" id="vwimpers"> Symptoom wimper</div>
<div class="test33" id="vwenkbrauw"> Symptoom wenkbrauw</div>
<div class="test44" id="vooghoek"> Symptoom ooghoek</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the result to be that when I click one of the areas above, the corresponding div shows and all other divs hide.

Comment: Maybe this wil clarify the whole situation, if have set up a test domain so you guys can see what i mean test.testdomein.expert/# <--- this is my code. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that ?

```js
const AlldivTest = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

document.querySelector('#Map').onclick =e=>{
  if (!e.target.matches('area')) return;
  e.stopPropagation();

  AlldivTest.forEach(d=>{
    if (d.id===e.target.dataset.elm)
      { d.style.display = (d.style.display==='none') ? 'block' : 'none' }
    else
      { d.style.display = 'none' }
  })
}
```

```css
.test { display: none; border:1px solid grey; padding: 5px 10px }
img { width:550px; height:550px }
```

```html
<div class="div-voog">
  <img class="map" src="images/tekening-oog-vrouw-550px.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area data-elm="vooglid" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly"
      coords=170,251,159,253,140,251,134,249,126,244,121,241,118,237,114,226,113,221,118,214,128,204,141,195,160,187,176,178,194,171,208,165,230,157,249,155,268,153,284,151,300,151,326,154,341,158,358,168,371,178,380,190,394,209,402,221,408,235,412,244,403,247,392,242,378,231,366,219,347,207,334,203,316,199,286,199,263,203,246,208,221,218" />
    <area data-elm="vwimpers" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly"
      coords="170,251,159,253,140,251,134,249,126,244,121,241,118,237,114,226,113,221,118,214,128,204,141,195,160,187,176,178,194,171,208,165,230,157,249,155,268,153,284,151,300,151,326,154,341,158,358,168,371,178,380,190,394,209,402,221,408,235,412,244,403,247,392,242,378,231,366,219,347,207,334,203,316,199,286,199,263,203,246,208,221,218" />
    <area data-elm="vwenkbrauw" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly"
      coords="43,157,62,120,84,103,114,85,132,75,151,65,191,47,204,38,232,31,268,31,298,31,317,31,339,33,365,42,390,47,408,51,429,59,445,61,467,69,484,74,501,85,504,127,498,141,494,146,471,136,446,123,432,119,412,113,396,108,376,100,362,96,354,93,334,90,321,90,308,89,295,87,271,83,260,81,232,75,218,74,207,73,192,73,181,76,150,95,122,109,102,118,78,138,62,149,54,158,49,163,47,167" />
    <area data-elm="vooghoek" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly"
      coords="388,275,396,270,401,270,407,266,408,263,411,258,420,263,425,269,428,273,432,278,435,280,434,282,434,285,422,284,414,279" />
  </map>
</div>

<div class="test" id="vooglid"> Symptoom ooglid</div>
<div class="test" id="vwimpers"> Symptoom wimper</div>
<div class="test" id="vwenkbrauw"> Symptoom wenkbrauw</div>
<div class="test" id="vooghoek"> Symptoom ooghoek</div>
```

[edit] 
For a quick see of "my" part of code you have to use **only one script** and it should b: like this

```
<script>
  $(function () {

    $('.map').maphilight({
      fade: false
    });

    $('.map').maphilight({
      fillColor: '008800'
    });

    $('#hilightlink')
    .mouseover(function (e) { $('#square2').mouseover(); })
    .mouseout(function (e)  { $('#square2').mouseout();  })
    .click(function (e)     { e.preventDefault();        });

    $('#linkerbeenlink')
    .click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $('#linkerbeen').data('maphilight') || {};
      data.neverOn = !data.neverOn;
      $('#linkerbeen').data('maphilight', data);
    });

    $('#linkerbeen,#linkerbeenlink2')
    .click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $('#linkerbeen').mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
      data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
      $('#linkerbeen').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });


    $('#vinger2link')
    .click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $('#vinger2').data('maphilight') || {};
      data.neverOn = !data.neverOn;
      $('#vinger2').data('maphilight', data);
    });

    $('#vinger2,#vinger2link2')
    .click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = $('#vinger2').mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
      data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
      $('#vinger2').data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });

    const AlldivTest = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

    document.querySelector('#Map').onclick =e=>{
      if (!e.target.matches('area')) return;

      e.stopPropagation();

      AlldivTest.forEach(d=>{
        if (d.id===e.target.dataset.elm)
          { d.style.display = (d.style.display==='none') ? 'block' : 'none' }
        else
          { d.style.display = 'none' }
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this piece of code does not work for me either. when i use it. The div's don't show at all just as the first comment of code above when i click the area's.

Comment: and there is nothing in your debugger ?? !!

Comment: every browser have a debugger, use F12

Comment: I do not have a debugger installed and i do not know how to install one but here is what my inspector says.
                                                                                                                          "oog-vrouw.php:100 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
oog-vrouw.php:105 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at oog-vrouw.php:105
(anonymous) @ oog-vrouw.php:105"

Comment: on whitch system are you running this code? ibm 370?

Comment: Maybe this wil clarify the whole situation, if have set up a test domain so you guys can see what i mean http://www.test.testdomein.expert/# <--- this is my code. and this is your code ---> http://www.test.testdomein.expert/misterjojo.php i hope this helps!

Comment: ... what to say... first you use jQuery and you din't notice that.

Comment: my code is correct, but you din't place it on the right place, and you have error code og your own code

Comment: I made change in my answer, It is a first step to correct your code. ?

Comment: You are a hero for me thank you man. And i feel very dumb for not even noticing that i had text/javascript there instead of just script. I thank you for helping out so quick ;) and yes i will be fixing my code now!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first hide all the other elements, so that then you can show the one you want to see. You could change all of them to have the class="test" and then prepend to your script something like this:

```
var tests = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
for (i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  tests[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

UPDATE
The full script would be something like this:

```
<script>
  function toggle_visibility(el) {
    var tests = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    for (i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
      tests[i].style.display = "none";
    } 
    el.style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

And the html:

```
<div>
  <area class="test" onclick="toggle_visibility(this)">A</div>
  <area class="test" onclick="toggle_visibility(this)">B</div>
  <area class="test" onclick="toggle_visibility(this)">C</div>
  <area class="test" onclick="toggle_visibility(this)">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this piece of code does not work for me. when i use it. The div's don't show at all when i click the area's.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery code that will work for hiding all other div when you click on current div

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
   var target = $(this).attr('vooglid');
   $("test"+target).show().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

but you must change your ids for apply that code

Comment: If i may ask were do i have to change my id's exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have tried adding all other div's to a CSS class?

Try this code:

```
function toggle_visibility(var id){
    $("#vooglid").addClass("hide_div");
    $("#vooghoek").addClass("hide_div");
    $("#vwimpers").addClass("hide_div");
    $("#id").removeClass("hide_div");
});
```

CSS:

```
.hide_div{
    display: none;
}
```

I did this a few months ago and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for updating

Comment: I tried your piece of code. It does work your piece of code. But it ends in the same result as mine. It shows and hide's the div's. But it does not fix the problem that when i click on 2 seperate div's the content over laps each other, and does not close when you click the second div